# Razor multi-line inline templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do you define a multi-line inline template?

For example, this grid has an inline template (the format parameter of the last column). What is the syntax to have multiple lines of html in the inline template?

```
@model List<Employee>
@{
    View.Title = "Employee List";
}
@{        

   var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,
                defaultSort: "FirstName",
                rowsPerPage: 3);
}
<p>
<h2>Employee List</h2>
<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "head",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("FirstName"),
            grid.Column("LastName"),
            grid.Column("Salary",format:@<text>$@item.Salary</text>)
        )
    )
</div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just be able to have multiple lines like the fllowing:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("FirstName"),
        grid.Column("LastName"),
        grid.Column("Salary",format:@<text>$@item.Salary<br/>
           <p>Here's another line</p>
           </text>)
    )
)
```

Are you seeing any particular issues?

Comment: Yes that works. I was not surrounding all content of the inline template with a <text> tag. Thank you.